# Hiding Angular services from being bundled in main js file after ng build

Tags: javascript, angular, build, compilation, angular-ngmodel

I have an application which loads most of its modules lazily. In these modules I use shared services to share data between several components. It's important to mention that I'm providing these services outside the lazy loaded module, **only** inside.

After running `ng build --prod` I examine the content of the main js file and I can see that the shared services content is located outside the lazy loaded module. In the company I'm working at, this is considered as a security issue and they want me to fix that straight away.

I already know that as part of the optimization process of Angular compilation, the shared services logic is bundled in the main file.

My question is - Is there a way to tell Angular to keep the lazy loaded services inside the lazy loaded module and not propagate it to the main js?